# Unable to bindProperty in flex to specific value

Tags: apache-flex, data-binding, flex4, mxml

I have a problem with my application in flex4, i have this code for my button:

```
<buttons:MyButton id="btnNewPost"
    label="{I18nManager.getInstance().main.newPost}"
    minWidth="170"
    click="{doSomething()}"
    creationComplete="btnNewPost_creationCompleteHandler(event)"/>
```

And on creation complete i have this code:

```
if (this.newItemButtonEnabledWithCategories)
{
    BindingUtils.bindProperty(this.btnNewPost, "enabled", ModelLocator.getInstance(), "currentCategory");
}
```

Well, so this is clear, when property `currentCategory` is not null, then the button will be enabled.

What i want:

I want to dind the property enable to another property of the `ModelLocator`, `itemMode` but only if itemMod is **ready**

I tried `BindingUtils.bindProperty(this.btnNewPost, "enabled", ModelLocator.getInstance(), "itemMode");` without luck because if itemMode has any value then the property `enabled` is always `true`

Is there any way to only enable item if `itemMode` is **ready**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use bindSetter rather than bindProperty.  This allows you to have a method handle when the property has changed:

```
BindingUtils.bindSetter(itemModeChanged, 
                        ModelLocateor.getInstance(), 
                        "itemMode");

protected function itemModeChanged(mode:String):void
{
    this.btnNewPost.enabled = (mode == "ready");
}
```

(As another thought, is there any reason you can't specify the binding in the MXML?  `enabled="{ModelLocator.getInstance().itemMode == 'ready'}`  I haven't tried this exact example to verify it works, but I think it should.)

Comment: Thanks a lot Bill, this guide me into the right direction. And answering your question, i can't bind directly to the parameter because when other component change the property from the modellocator, then the button will be enabled

Answer (score 0):

You could bind to a new property, `itemModeIsReady` in your `ModelLocator`.  In your setter for `itemMode`, dispatch a `PropertyChangeEvent` for `itemModeIsReady` and have an appropriate getter:

```
public function set itemMode(mode:String):void {
  var previousValue = _itemMode;
  //existing 
  dispatchEvent(PropertyChangeEvent.createUpdateEvent(this, "itemModeIsReady", previousValue == "ready", mode == "ready"));
}

[Bindable]
public function get itemModeIsReady():Boolean {
  return itemMode == "ready";
}
```